# Equation of vector on line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

This is an exercise in Ch. 4 of Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry*, on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that they are considered as points throughout this text.

Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be vectors, and $l_1, l_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $l_1+l_2=\|\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\|$. Let $\mathbf{c}$ be a unique point on line segment $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$ such that $l_1=\|\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}\|$ and $l_2=\|\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{b}\|$. By writing $\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}=t(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$, prove that $$\mathbf{c}=\frac{l_1}{l_1+l_2}\mathbf{a}+\frac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}\mathbf{b}.$$ What is the midpoint of $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$?

So far, I have $t=\frac{l_1}{l_1+l_2}$, and hence that $\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}=\frac{l_1}{l_1+l_2}(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$. Similarly, $\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{b}=\frac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$. What now?

Comment: Can be good to use some notation which clarifies what are vectors and what are scalars. It makes formula easier to understand.

Comment: I usually just omit lines/boldface simply because I find it tedious. I'll embolden the vectors in this case, though, should anyone refer to this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $c-a=\dfrac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}(b-a)$, one deduces

$$c=a+\frac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}(b-a)=\frac{l_1+l_2}{l_1+l_2}a+\frac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}b-\frac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}a=$$

$$=\dfrac{l_1+l_2-l_2}{l_1+l_2}a+\dfrac{l_2}{l_1+l_2}b$$

whence the result.

Comment: Thank you. It should be $c-a=\frac{l_1}{l_1+ l_{2}}$ though: just a typing error.